# How to read Google Fit data with Tasker?

Tags: android, google-fit, tasker

How can I read data from Google Fit into a variable with Tasker?

More speficially, I want to read e.g. my current step count for today which is counted by my phone + a fitness tracker and given to Google Fit. My goal is to have a variable containing this number to then work with it. I've read about the Google Fit History API but I don't know how to access it via Tasker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did figure it out after a day of trial and error. It's a rather "complicated" procedure.

**Preparation:**

*Step 1* - Create a project on https://console.developers.google.com/project and get a client ID as well as the secret. (There's plenty of more detailed tutorials on that). The project needs to be configured as an app - not as a web thingy. You also need to add `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` to the redirection URLs. (`http://localhost` may stay there)

*Step 2* - Install RESTask Plugin for Tasker.

*Step 3* - Goto `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID`. You will get a code there. Copy that code.

*Step 4* - Create a Task which will use the RESTask plugin action. Configure it to:

```
Request Type: POST
Host: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

Check `Enable custom body`

Set the custom body to: `code=%THE_COPIED_CODE&client_id=%YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code`

Switch to `Header` and press `Add more`:

```
Name: Content-Type
Value: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

You'll get a return code 200 if everything went fine.
Split the returned response (`%rtres`) with `splitter` `"`. Save your token which lies within `%rtres4` and your refresh token which lies within `%rtres14`.

**Getting Step Count**

*Step 1* - Before getting anything, you need to have a valid token. The token obtained during the preparation is only valid for a limited amount of time. You can request a new token with the refresh token that you should have saved. To get a working token, redo *Step 4* with a different body:

`client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&refresh_token=YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN&grant_type=refresh_token`

Repeat the splitting and the fresh token will be saved in `%rtres4`.

*Step 2* - Now you can finally get the precious data. At first, define a start and end time (saved in `%start` and `%end`). Note that those have to be in nanoseconds. You may use `%TIMEMS*1000000`. Therefore, add a RESTask action with the following configuration:

```
Request Type: GET
Host: https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps/datasets/%start-%end
```

Do **not** check `Enable custom body`

Switch to `Header` and press `Add more` (3 times):

```
Name: Content-Type
Value: application/json

Name: Authorization
Value: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN

Name: X-JavaScript-User-Agent
Value: Google APIs Explorer
```

You'll get a return code 200 if everything went fine. The step counts will be returned in the response.

Feel free to do whatever you want with this data. To get the complete step count, you may need to summarize the values. (Split the response and iterate with a for loop). I did chose to pass the step count to a Zooper Widget to have my own custom Google Fit step count widget on the homescreen.

Comment: I get an `redirect_uir_mismatch`. What URL do I have to set when creating a client ID?

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst Try adding: `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`

Comment: I can't set the redirection URLs. Google changed the website and it looks different from the other tutorials. I keep getting a 401 error without the redirection.